# Sometimes this method for detecting user interaction doesn't work

Tags: android, android-windowmanager

my Android application has to detect the user interactions in order to use method A or method B in a loop.

I call this method in the onCreate() of the MainActivity...

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
private void detectUserInteraction() {
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            0, 0, 0, 0,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    final WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    if (wm != null) {
        final View view = new View(this);
        view.setOnTouchListener((v, event) -> {
            UserInteractionManager.getInstance().setRecentUserInteraction(true);
            return false;
        });
        wm.addView(view, params);
    }
}
```

...and is not working for a few part of the users (latest Huawei owners). I have the log files of these users and the method only works as I expected a few minutes.

Anyone has any idea to fix the issue of the method?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Sounds like an Android vendor fragmentation issue. I've experienced this many times with the camera functionality. Must be that Huawei phones are overwriting this functionality at the kernel level for their own customization purposes. You might have to consider reaching out to an Huawei representative to get the full scoop.

Comment: Sure your app isn't just getting killed because it's in the background? If you have the events log buffer (i.e. `logcat -bevents`; the default logcat output only contains the system/main/crash log buffers) from these users, see if you can find a `am_proc_died` or `am_kill` (maybe `am_stop...` something too?) there. Really, any mentions of your package name in the logs might be interesting.